# change program attribute in Aldon

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have a program defined to have attribute type RPGLE in Aldon. Is there any option to change this to SQLRPGLE ?

I have gone through the various options in the green screen version and also the LMi RDi plugin but no such options could be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check the object out.
2. From the Work with Objects By Developer screen
3. 16 (Change object)
4. Change the object Attribute from RPGLE to SQLRPGLE

Aldon will track both the SQL and non-SQL versions of the object till the version you changed in DEV is promoted back to Production.